# pronunciation of 一昨年

Tags: word-choice, readings, multiple-readings

[My dictionary](http://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%80%E6%98%A8%E5%B9%B4) lists both いっさくねん and おととし as readings of 一昨年. Which of these are commonly used? Is there any difference between these two readings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

おととし is far more common in everyday conversations with your friends and colleagues, whereas いっさくねん is used mainly in formal speeches and presentations. いっさくねん is the on-yomi of this word, so it's not surprising that いっさくねん sounds more formal and/or technical than おととし.

However, when people write おととし, they tend to use hiragana (it depends on the writer's taste). This is partly because おととし is a non-straightforward 熟字訓.

> 7.「一昨日」「明後日」「一昨年」は、「おととい」「あさって」「おととし」というように、ふつうひらがなで書きます。(from [東京外国語大学言語モジュール](http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/mt/ja/gmod/courses/c02/lesson12/step1/explanation/020.html))

So when you see 一昨年 actually written on paper, and have to read it out loud, いっさくねん may be a better choice.